# Conditional Statement: not sure why it gets the Undefined results (JavaScipt )

Tags: javascript

I'm a noob to JavaScript and I'm just learning the basic, no idea why only half of this code works.

```
var quartet = ["abasd", "bsdfa", "ccvssw"];
console.log("quartet.length : " + quartet.length);
console.log(quartet[0]);
console.log(quartet[1]);
console.log(quartet[2]);

if (quartet.length = 1) {
    console.log("It's just a Solo");
} else if (quartet.length = 2) {
    console.log("It's just a Duo");
} else if (quartet.length = 3) {
    console.log("It's just a Trio");
} else if (quartet.length = 4) {
    console.log("Perfect, a quartet, just right");
} else {
    console.log("Either too many or nobody");
};

for (var i = 0; i <= quartet.length; i++) {
    console.log(quartet[i] + " : " + i)
};
```

But any attempt of making this Conditional Statement works inside VS Code results into this

```
quartet.length : 3
abasd
bsdfa
ccvssw
It's just a Solo
abasd : 0
undefined : 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare numbers using `==` instead of `=`. Also, the `for loop` condition should be `i < quartet.length` instead of `i <= quartet.length`:

```js
var quartet = ["abasd", "bsdfa", "ccvssw"];
console.log("quartet.length : " + quartet.length);
console.log(quartet[0]);
console.log(quartet[1]);
console.log(quartet[2]);

if (quartet.length == 1) {
    console.log("It's just a Solo");
} else if (quartet.length == 2) {
    console.log("It's just a Duo");
} else if (quartet.length == 3) {
    console.log("It's just a Trio");
} else if (quartet.length == 4) {
    console.log("Perfect, a quartet, just right");
} else {
    console.log("Either too many or nobody");
};

for (var i = 0; i < quartet.length; i++) {
    console.log(quartet[i] + " : " + i)
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `==` (or `===`, preferably) for comparison; [using `=` will assign to `quartet.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) which will truncate the array.

So,

```
if (quartet.length == 1) {
```

etc.